# How to check whether cocoapod is installed or not in mac? If available then what is the version?

Tags: bash, macos, cocoapods

I am typing command pod --version in terminal but after tapping enter getting -bash: pod: command not found.

Answer (score 3):

Just type

```
pod --version
```

in your terminal, if pod is not installed it will show

```
pod: command not found
```

If pod is installed you will get version number